# How can I split a string value in a SQL Server CE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a table containing a `nvarchar` column `[AffectedNodes]` that looks something like this when you take a peek at its contents (two variations shown):

```
"MID128; MID129; MID130"
"[1,3,2]; [3,1,2]"
```

We are working on a change which will move the `AffectedNodes` into its own table `[AffectedNode]` that has a `nvarchar` column `[NodeId]`, which should store one of the nodes from the above string. I'm tasked with migrating the existing content to the new format.

As you can see the values are split using `semi-column` and a `space`.

To follow the database upgrade process they use in our project I have to write an SQL query in SQL Server CE. I'm wondering how I could do this in a neat way. Thanks!

Comment: What is the maximum number of values that might be in the string?

Comment: Theoretically there's no real maximum, but in reality we would expect them to be between 1-10'ish.

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE supports, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING function, did you check that out or did you see any issue with them?